# HttpWebRequest login

Tags: c#, authentication

I am trying to login to an https website , and when i run the code ,I dont get an error but im not logged in either, So i would like to know what is the problem
I used the same code and technique for an http website (with different postdata string obviousely) and it logged me in
here is the code:

```
string postData = "JAVASCRIPT_ON=userName=XXXX&password=XXX&loginAction=Logon";
            CookieContainer tempCookies = new CookieContainer();
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            Byte[] byteData = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://direct.gov.mb.ca/ppr/actions/loginDispatcher");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.CookieContainer = tempCookies;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Referer = "https://direct.gov.mb.ca/ppr/jsps/login/login.jsp";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
            request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            requestStream.Close();


        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        tempCookies.Add(response.Cookies);
        loginCookies = tempCookies;
```

Comment: You should pass the length of the byte array, not the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `CookieContainer` property of all of your requests to the same instance.

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies, non of the suggestions worked, as i said i use the same code for a different http website and it logged in no probelm, so i dont think those are the problems, any other ideas. A hint would be, when i do login it redirects from login page to another page, but that page is not for members ,(I should see a members page)

Comment: @roy: Use Fiddler to compare your fake request to a real login request from a browser.

Comment: the only differences are as follow

Comment: CONNECT direct.gov.mb.ca:443 HTTP/1.1  (in my program)  CONNECT direct.gov.mb.ca:443 HTTP/1.0 (with browser)     also the browser has client: user-aAgent:....   and Entity: Content Length:0                                                             my program did not generate those in the request header which is wired how can i generate them

Comment: also my SessionID is empty, but the real login has sessionID

Comment: You may need to request the login form to get a session.  Enable HTTPS decryption in Fiddler and compare the actual requests.

Comment: That probably wouldn't make a difference, but try adding it.

Comment: /ppr/actions/login.jsp has 2 cookies in its header, mine doesnt have those cookies, which is wired because i copy and paste  /ppr/actions/login.jsp in the browser and it already has cookies in its header, what should i do

Comment: how to get cookies for my header for my initial page??

Comment: They probably come from some other page (eg, the original login form, or the homepage)